# How to find the memory address offsets from IDA in binary file

Tags: bash, command-line, hex, ida

I am trying to write a command line application which can modify a .so file using hex values at specific addresses.

I'm using IDA Demo and HxD Hex Editor to attain the addresses which need to be updated, however, each time I try to modify the file, no matter which language I use (bash scripting, php, python) every time I edit the file, it updates from the wrong address offsets which I have from IDA and HxD Hex Editor.

I have seen a few posts regarding this, but as of yet, none have been able to give a definitive answer as to how to attain the addresses which HxD and IDA have no issue finding :(

In python I have used the mmap function to attempt this using the below;

```
import mmap
import contextlib
import os

filesize = os.stat("filetomodify.so").st_size
print int(filesize)


with open("filetomodify.so", 'r+b') as f:
    with contextlib.closing(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),  access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)) as m:
        m[0x173596] = "FF 20"
        m[0x18D88E] = "FF 20"
        m.close()
```

This uses the `os` library to determine the size of the file which is returned as `10025936`, however, each time I add the `length=filesize` argument between `f.fileno()` and `access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE` I always get a `mmap.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` Error Message, but when I omit the argument, I get a `m: TypeError: Required argument 'length' (pos 2) not found`

The bash script I have used is one which I found here, which modifies the file okay, but updates the wrong addresses;

```
#!/bin/bash

# param 1: file
# param 2: offset
# param 3: value
# param 4: Size of Bytes
function replaceByte() {
    printf "$(printf '\\x%02X' $3)" | dd of="$1" bs=$4 seek=$2 count=1 conv=notrunc &> /dev/null
}

# Usage:
replaceByte 'filetomod.so' "0x173596" "95 E5 0A 2F 66 1E 32 EE 4C B8 9A 6E BD EC 01" 15
```

Calling the function as described above updates the file and writes it ok, but when I do a find for the updated byte string (e.g, 95 E5 0A 2F 66 1E 32 EE 4C B8 9A 6E BD EC 01 -- Just a long unique string which you would not expect to find in a file) it has been inserted at the incorrect address, or it tells me that the offset is outside of the file size.

Lastly, the php code I used (which I wasn't expecting much success with anyway) was;

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('binary_file.bin', 'w+b');
fseek($fp, 173596, );   
fwrite($fp, '95 E5 0A 2F 66 1E 32 EE 4C B8 9A 6E BD EC 01');
fclose($fp);
?>
```

However, rather than editing the Hex values of the binary file, this added the string as a string to the binary file at HxD Address `0002A61C` with the hex code as `39 35 20 45 35 20 30 41 20 32 46 20 36 36 20 31 45 20 33 32 20 45 45 20 34 43 20 42 38 20 39 41 20 36 45 20 42 44 20 45 43 20 30 31` which had the output of `95 E5 0A 2F 66 1E 32 EE 4C B8 9A 6E BD EC 01`

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. My only requirement for the answers would be that it can be run from command line, whether php, bash, python, java etc.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not know anything about python and php. About the bash function, I cannot understand the way you are trying to modify the file. The `dd` command copies the standard input to the file but... that standard input is just a few characters. How do you copy the other unaltered bytes, i.e., the bytes before the desired position (address) and the bytes after the desired address?

Comment: Hi @Jdamian; the `conv=notrunc` overrides the default of truncating the remainder of the file, and the bytes before the offset are not overwritten when you seek the offset... as far as I know.

Comment: thanks. I never used `dd` to modify a file before.

Comment: Me either before I started working on this. I thought it was only for making CD's / DVD's before that :)

Comment: Un the command `printf '\\x%02X' $3`, the `%02X` only applies on the first value of `$3`, not on all. The output of that command should be `\x95 E5 0A 2F 66 1E 32 EE 4C B8 9A 6E BD EC 01`.

Comment: You are right, the actual string should be ` %02X\x95 %02X\xE5 %02X\x0A %02X\x2F %02X\x66 %02X\x1E %02X\x32 %02X\xEE %02X\x4C %02X\xB8 %02X\x9A %02X\x6E %02X\xBD %02X\xEC %02X\x01` so that the output represents `0x95 0xE5 0x0A 0x2F 0x66....` That's what I get for copy & pasting from my testing file.

However, the values were never the issue. The issue is the offset, and not being able to offset the file correctly, i.e. in IDA / HxD fashion.

Comment: Hey, I realized that the value for seek and skip parameters are given en BLOCKS, not in BYTES. Therefore, the address given in your example 0x173596 is not understood as an address -- dd starts writing after skiping 0x173596 blocks of 15 bytes size, because you have used bs, not ibs.

Comment: I'm not sure if `dd` command understand the hexadecimal values in its parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trials in a virtual machine running Centos 6.5, I got it

```
function replaceByte() {
    printf "$(printf '\\x%02X' $3)" |
    dd of="$1" ibs=1 count=1 obs=1 seek="$2" conv=notrunc &> /dev/null
}
```

The problem is the unit of the `seek` parameter: BLOCKS, not BYTES.

When you change the default block size, both input block size and output block size are changed. Therefore the `seek` parameter refers to blocks whose size is the value of `bs` parameter.

To solve this, you must set the input block size `ibs` as youd did **but** the output block size `obs` must be set to 1. Otherwise, as output is a disk file, the `obs` value is set to 512 bytes (the disk block size).

You can try the following test to check the size of the output block is 512, not 1:

1. Create a text file (file.txt) containing an entire blank line (for example, 30 white spaces)
2. Check that the size of the file is near 30 bytes.
3. Run `echo -e '\x41' | dd if=file.txt ibs=1 count=1 seek=3 conv=notrunc`  (0x41 is the ASCII code for A)
4. Check that the size of file.txt has changed: 1537 bytes (3 blocks of 512 bytes per block plus 1 -- 3*512+1)
5. As file.txt is "corrupted", repeat the steps 1 and 2.
6. Run `echo -e '\x41' | dd if=file.txt ibs=1 count=1 obs=1 seek=3 conv=notrunc`
7. Check that the size of file.txt has not changed.
8. Look the contents of the file and check that there is an 'A' replacing the 4th blank.

Best regards.

P.D: this funcion `replaceByte()` should work fine for just ONE byte. If you need to change several contiguous bytes in a single call, you must replace the `printf`, perhaps, with a loop... and the `ibs=1` with the proper value.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this response.
However, I do have a couple of questions; 
1 - With regards the loop you mentioned if I were to call the function with 1 byte at a time i.e. `9B`, how would I then update the offset if I am using the HxD / IDA address, which is hex based 1-9 A-F? 
2 - Where you mentioned the `ibs` and `obs`, do they have to be the same size? or would `obs` be set to 1 regardless of what `ibs` is set to?
Sorry if this further confuses the matter :(

Comment: 1. To convert hexadecimal values to decimal values you may use `printf`, for example, `printf "%d" 0x20`. 2. NO, in fact, they may be different. The `obs=1` is needed to point to the right address (`seek` parameter). The `ibs=1` prevents inserting more bytes from the `printf` than ONE. But if you want your function to insert more than one byte (a _byte-string_), the `ibs` parameter must be changed to right value (the length of the _byte-string_).

Comment: Right, this is my code at the minute; `function replaceByte() {
   printf $3 | dd of="$1" ibs=$4 obs=1 seek=$2 count=1 conv=notrunc &> /dev/null
}

# Usage:
replaceByte 'libgame.so' "0x18D88E" "\x95\xE5\x0A\x2F\x66\x1E\x32\xEE\x4C\xB8\x9A\x6E\xBD\xEC\x01\x3D" 16`; If i set the offset to 0, then it prints the string of bytes fine. However when I try to put an offset like the one above(`0x18D88E`) i.e. one with a letter in it. It cannot find the address... and I have no idea how to calculate it based on the values in it. Is there an easy way to convert these offsets to binary?

Comment: Have you read my previous answer to your first question? You must **convert** the hexadecimal value to decimal, and this must be used in the `seek` parameter -- `seek=$2` works fine when `$2` is a decimal value.

Comment: You are 100% right. Apologies, I was having a really dumbed down day yesterday.
Thanks again for all your help!