# Change the header in a huge file without rewriting the whole file

Tags: bash, sed, header, dd

I got a problem with huge data files. The headers of these files count 79 lines. After these lines the data is binary. I want to change the header via bash script. I used sed until now. The problem is that when i just want to change the header, either the whole data file is read and written (1) or the process is aborted after those 79 lines (2). I need to change the header in 8 lines. Therefore my commands referring to that problem are:

(1)

```
sed -i  '1,79 s/ConverterPositionM2C1='"$M2C1"'/ConverterPositionM2C1='"$M2C1N"'/' $FileName
```

(2)

```
sed -i -e '79q' -e 's/ConverterPositionM1C2='"$M1C2"'/ConverterPositionM1C2='"$M1C2N"'/' $FileName
```

Using the first command works in all cases but it takes hours for huge files (20GB). Because i want to change parameters in 8 lines, which differ from each another, I need to put 8 of these commands in my script and the execution of the script takes even longer.
The second command only copies the header. The data is lost.

Comment: Critical issue: Is the changed 79-line header of the exact same length as the input header?  If not, can you pad the header, say with blanks, to make it so for all future changes?

Comment: @John1024 I only change numeric values. But indeed it can happen that `100.00000` becomes `10.00000` (not `010.00000`). The number of lines stays the same.

Comment: The number of lines is not important.  The number of bytes is.  If you change the number of bytes in the header, then the binary data has to be moved.  Would it be possible for `100.00000` to change to `10.00000 ` with either a leading or trailing space to keep the number of bytes the same?

Comment: @John1024 I think it should be possible. Although i am not sure how the later used analysing software handles the extra precision or the additional space. I would prefer adding an extra 0.

Comment: Perhaps you are interested in this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146618/how-to-find-the-memory-address-offsets-from-ida-in-binary-file)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will keep this in mind. Actually that is not main problem right now. My problem is the time consuming factor in my code. My aim is to just change the header and save these changes. But either the whole file is read (case (1)) or the data is lost (case (2)). If i do the changes manually it just takes about some time to open the file but changes are quite instant. The script runs for hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to rewrite the binary data, then *the length of the header in bytes must not change*.  You can do this by padding with spaces or zeroes or whatever works for your format.

The first step is to create the header that you want.  You may use something like:

```
sed 's/old/new/; 79q' "$FileName" >newhdr
```

Replace `s/old/new/` with whatever substitution commands you need but remember that, when all is done, the length of the header in bytes must not change.  `79q` tells `sed` to stop after it reads the 79th line.  The new header is written to a temporary file called `newhdr`.

If `newhdr` has the form that you want, then we need to change it in-place in `$FileName`.  This can be done with `dd` as follows:

```
dd conv=notrunc obs=1 if=newhdr of="$NewFile"
```

`conv=notrunct` tells `dd` not to truncate the output file.  `obs=1` tells it to use single byte blocks.  `if` specifies the input file and `of` specifies the output file.  After this command is executed, `$NewFile` will be updated in place.

Comment: thanks i will try that out and reply with the result

Answer (score 0):

I was informed about [the solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790306/joining-streams?noredirect=1#comment1187856_790306). In, Unix world, you can

```
echo $NEW_HEADER | cat - <(dd if=$YOUR_FILE bs=1 skip=$HEADER_SIZE_TO_STRIP)
```

This reads your file, strips the header amount of bytes and prefixes the file with new header (`eol` included).